# What could cause a gain error in the R-2R DAC?

Tags: resistors, dac, r2r

I was studying R-2R ladders and I still what causes a gain error in the R-2R.  I assume that it could be caused by an error in the R or 2R resistors.  I don't think that a mismatch in the feedback resistor of the opamp would cause any offset error. Also I am unsure how a mismatch in one of the  R or 2R resistors causes a gain error and not just a DNL and INL.

Comment: What are your assumptions for switch losses and bias offsets

Comment: If the all R's are not equal, then the result at each node is a declining % error voltage, or a gain error.

Comment: Is this SAR system based on some real facts, or it's a cloud based problem, and you can't sleep at night? You are asking this twice but still there is no any information about the problem, measurements, setup, results,....

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, I suspect it is a home assignment, theoretical. That's why no sleep...